# Class active no menu include

Tags: php, html, php-5

Em minhas páginas `PHP` utilizo um `include` para chamar um arquivo que contém meu menu:

```
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
```

Arquivo com menu:

```
<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">Hosting</a>
<ul>
   <li><a href="hosting-shared.php">SHARED HOSTING</a></li>
   <li><a href="free-hosting.php">FREE HOSTING</a></li>
   <li><a href="cloud-hosting.php">CLOUD HOSTING</a></li>
   <li><a href="reseller-hosting.php">RESELLER HOSTING</a></li>                
</ul>
</li>
   <li><a href="domains.php">DOMAINS</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Servers</a>
<ul>
   <li><a href="cloud-vps.php">CLOUD VPS</a></li>
   <li><a href="dedicated-servers.php">DEDICATED SERVERS</a></li>
   <li><a href="order-slider.php">ORDER SLIDER</a></li>
```

Quando o menu está ativo fica com essa class

```
class="current-menu-item"
```

Como faço para inserir a `class` `active` apenas no menu acessado?

Answer (score 1):

Faça o *menu.php* assim:

```
<?php
    /**
    * Verifica o script ativo e compara com $script indicado;
    * Se a comparação for positiva, imprime a CLASS;
    * Se a comparação falhar, retorna FALSE.
    * @return string|boolean
    */
    function setClass($script = NULL){
        $ativo = str_replace('/','',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        if($ativo == $script){
            echo 'class="current-menu-item"';
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
?>
<li><a <?=setClass('testing.php')?> href="testing.php">Hosting</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a <?=setClass('hosting-shared.php')?> href="hosting-shared.php">SHARED HOSTING</a></li>
            <li><a <?=setClass('free-hosting.php')?> href="free-hosting.php">FREE HOSTING</a></li>
            <li><a <?=setClass('cloud-hosting.php')?> href="cloud-hosting.php">CLOUD HOSTING</a></li>
            <li><a <?=setClass('reseller-hosting.php')?> href="reseller-hosting.php">RESELLER HOSTING</a></li>
         </ul>
</li>
<li><a <?=setClass('domains.php')?> href="domains.php">DOMAINS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Servers</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a <?=setClass('cloud-vps.php')?> href="cloud-vps.php">CLOUD VPS</a></li>
            <li><a <?=setClass('dedicated-servers.php')?> href="dedicated-servers.php">DEDICATED SERVERS</a></li>
            <li><a <?=setClass('order-slider.php')?> href="order-slider.php">ORDER SLIDER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Isso é uma outra opção sem uso de PHP!

Uma vez é algo visual acredito que possa ser tratado no lado do cliente, usando Javascript/Jquery.

Por exemplo:

```
var pagina = window.location.pathname.split('/')[ window.location.pathname.split('/').length - 1 ];

$('.menu').find('a[href="'+pagina+'"]').closest('li').addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Supondo que essa isto:

```
<div class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Hosting</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="hosting-shared.php">SHARED HOSTING</a></li>
       <li><a href="free-hosting.php">FREE HOSTING</a></li>
       <li><a href="cloud-hosting.php">CLOUD HOSTING</a></li>
       <li><a href="reseller-hosting.php">RESELLER HOSTING</a></li>                
    </ul>
</div>
```

O `JQuery` irá buscar pelo `a` que possua `href` igual à página que o usuário está acessando, então irá localizar o `li` mais próximo e então adicionar a classe `current-menu-item` nele.

**Basicamente funcionará assim:**

1. Encontra qualquer elemento de  classe `menu`
2. Encontra `a` com `href` igual a variável `pagina`
3. Encontra `li` mais próximo
4. Adiciona classe `current-menu-item`